# How to handle Webdriver error in protractor - Multiple File Upload

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am validating that user is not allowed to upload multiple files my code is as below -

spec file :

```js
    agentPage.importMultipleFile('affidavit1.pdf','affidavit2.pdf');
```

method used -

```js
importMultipleFile(filename1:any,filename2:any){
        const fileToUpload1 = '../testData/'+filename1;
        const absolutePath1 = path.resolve(__dirname,fileToUpload1);
        const fileToUpload2 = '../testData/'+filename2;
        const absolutePath2 = path.resolve(__dirname,fileToUpload2);
        WebLibraryUtils.GetElement('css','#customFile').sendKeys(absolutePath1+"\n" +absolutePath2).then(function(){

        }),function(err: string){
            throw new Error(err);
        }              
    }
```

I am getting this Error - How to handle this ?

```
- WebDriverError: invalid argument: the element can not hold multiple files
    (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b07dc18a74666574f19176731995c-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1155}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: but it is expected situation from you side, am I right?

Comment: Yes . This is expected but I need to handle this in the code. This causes the test to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think `try ... catch` should be fine here:

```js
async importMultipleFile(filename1: string, filename2: string) {
        const fileToUpload1 = `../testData/${filename1}`;
        const absolutePath1 = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload1);
        const fileToUpload2 = `../testData/${filename2}`;
        const absolutePath2 = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload2);
        try {
        await WebLibraryUtils.GetElement('css','#customFile').sendKeys(absolutePath1+"\n" +absolutePath2)
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
    }
```

so in test you could check it like:
`expectThrowException(await importMultipleFile)`. I don't know what assert library do you have, but the most of them have such method.

Comment: I still receive this error in console -  (node:3860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): WebDriverError: invalid argument: the element can not hold multiple files

Comment: if you don't want throw an error you can change `throw` to console.log("something here")

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked perfectly fine -

```js
WebLibraryUtils.GetElement('css','#customFile').sendKeys(absolutePath1+"\n" +absolutePath2).then(null,function(err){
            console.log("he error occurred is : "+ err.name);
           })
```